# Assign a value to a variable inside a loop

Tags: shell-script, here-string

I have this code :

```
HOSTS="host1 host2"
    For hostname in ${HOSTS} ;
do ssh -tt ${USERNAME}@${hostname} << EOF
HOSTSN="test"
echo ${HOSTSN}
exit
EOF
Done
```

The variable `HOSTSN` is empty, can you tell me why?

Comment: where is your here document ends ? EOF

Comment: I just updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HOSTSN is empty because it is being evaluated at the time of the

```
do ssh -tt ${USERNAME}@${hostname} << EOF
```

execution.  Using `echo \${HOSTSN}` instead will fix it.

Consider this example.  Here a file 'foo' is created.  The contents are not executed at the time of file creation.  So `$NAME` is not set to anything.

```
$ cat >foo <<EOF
NAME=Steve
echo Hello ${NAME}
EOF
$

$ cat foo
Hello
$
```

By introducing a `\` character, the variable is not evaluated at the time of file creation.

```
$ cat >foo <<EOF
NAME=Steve
echo Hello \${NAME}
EOF
$

$ cat foo
Hello Steve
$
```

Comment: Thanks Steve , it resolved my problem , can you explain me why I need to put the "\" before the variable in the loop ?

Comment: Can you give a pointer to where the usage of `\\` is explained?

Comment: @guntbert: The manual page of your shell. For example `man bash`, if your shell is Bash.